# Code Running On Spotfire 7.13 No Longer Works On 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, spotfire

I have a simple script here which I'm attempting to migrate from Spotfire 7.13 to Spotfire 10.0. As stated above I need to pass a value to an input field using jquery but this code  - which worked perfectly on 7.13 - only fills input field but value is not assigned to property.  Here's the code:

HTML

```
<span id="testInput"><SpotfireControl id="3f7bc58becb64338a5866a994a01aceb" /></span>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$("#testInput input").val("asd").blur();
```

Comment: So read the docs and find out what changed between versions. Major version 7 to 10 is a big upgrade and it undoubtedly brings a lot of changes with it.

Comment: I did but unfortunately the only thing about I could read on releas notes is: "Please note that the jQueryUI JavaScript library will not be distributed with future releases of TIBCO Spotfire®. Your use of this third party library, whether in this release, past releases, or future releases of TIBCO Spotfire, is entirely at your own discretion, as such use of the jQueryUI JavaScript library is not supported or warranted by TIBCO" which doesn't help me at all because input field gets correctly the value, but the associated Property doesn't get it

Comment: Also before downvote, please make sure that the user has actually asked a question whose solution could be found without posting on the forum rather than just say "read the documentation" without you knowing at all: 1) if this step has already been done 2) that there is actually the solution to the problem posed

Comment: Try adding this before the javascript you posted: `$("#testInput input").val("asd").focus();`

Comment: I tried but this doesn't work for me :(

Comment: @nbokmans this sort of change isn't generally listed in the documents. JQuery has always been sort of a wild west in Spotfire. to the downvoter, consider removing your downvote; this was an earnest question with a weird solution :)

Answer (score 0):

after some research and testing, it seems like you can't `.blur()` because you haven't `.focus()`ed. the following code worked for me.

HTML in the Textarea:

```
<span id="test"><SpotfireControl id="SOME INPUT PROPERTY CONTROL ID" /></span>

<SpotfireControl id="A LABEL FOR THE SAME DOCUMENT PROPERTY" />

<a href="#" id="clickme">Click Me</a>
```

attached JavaScript:

```
$("#clickme").on("click", function(e){

    $("#test input").val("asdfasdf").focus().blur();

});
```